# Configuring guard to monitor controller sub-directories

Tags: ruby, regex, guard

I'm new to ruby and I'm trying to configure guard to monitor controllers in a nested directory.

Here is the directory structure

```
/app
  /controllers
    /manage   
      /my_controller.rb
```

Here is the watch expression that should fire when the file `my_controller.rb` is edited

```
watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  
  { |m| [
    "spec/routing/#{m[2]}_routing_spec.rb", 
    "spec/#{m[3]}s/#{m[1]}/#{m[2]}_#{m[3]}_spec.rb", 
    "spec/acceptance/#{m[2]}_spec.rb"] 
  }
```

Note that i don't have `routing` or `acceptance` tests, I'm just trying to modify the existing controller watch statement to work with the controller in a nested directory.  Also, note that I was able to successfully watch the spec file for changes by adding the following line

`watch(%r{^spec/.+/.+_spec\.rb$})`

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't clearly understand your problem... What are you willing to do when your controller is modified?

Comment: Are you familiar with Guard for Ruby on Rails?

Comment: So just to be 100% sure. You do have a spec called: spec/controllers/manage/my_controller_spec.rb right?

Comment: @rainkinz -  yes.   I should mention that guard is running on a vagrant machine, the files are located on the host machine and accessible to vagrant via a fileshare. I had to configure guard to manually poll,  but it is catching other file changes (including guardfile)

Comment: Yes, I use the Zeus+Guard+Rails stack. But I mean, you want to run those three specs each time a controller is modified. What is the problem you have?

Comment: @Jason it seems like it should work. You've definitely restarted Guard right? Maybe restart Zeus too?

Comment: Also how are you starting Guard? bundle exec guard -p or similar?

Comment: @geekazoid -  I want to run the corresponding controller spec every time the controller changes.   I'm not using Zeus.  Launching guard with `bundle exec guard - l - p 5`

Comment: @Jason I suppose that the problem is that spec is not executed at all.

Just to dismiss other kind of problems, can you do `tail -f *somefile*`? If there is an error here, it must be something to do with inotify's watches.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, which file should i tail and what will it prove?  Other files are being monitored appropriately.

Comment: Thanks everyone this is operator error, i feel like a dummy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, @rainkinz had it right.  There was a typo in the specfile name that I couldn't see.  I used the `-d` switch when running `guard` which printed debug statements that brought the error to my attention.